# JSON reader was expecting a name but found ':'. in Mongodb Java

Tags: json, mongodb, mongo-java

I am storing my data from external file to mongodb in localhost. it's quite huge dataset of volume 1.70GB with ~10 million tweets. While importing from file to mongodb it shows me the error *"JSON reader was expecting a name but found ':'"*
I dint have any error on previous files. But this I cant figure it out. The data is just a real time collection of tweets from streaming API in a json format.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    int counter = 0;
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        Document old_status = Document.parse(line);
// If it is a deleted tweet, then continue
    if (old_status.containsKey("delete")) {
        continue;
    }
    //populate original tweets      
    Document original_status = new Document();
    if(line.contains("retweeted_status")){
    Document retweets = (Document)old_status.get("retweeted_status");
      original_status.append("status",retweets.get("text"));
      original_status.append("Likes",retweets.getInteger("favorite_count"));}}
```

its a sample code for importing data from file to mongo collection.
Help me to solve this. I really stuck in this place and it takes my time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that it can not parse a line from your file. Add logging to see what line causes a problem.

Comment: @ Andriy Simonov- The error in Json format. Curley braces were missing. What I want to do to skip when json is not in a correct format?

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, and also a little unrelated to this specific question, but google brought me here so going to leave an answer.

I got this error when I was trying to parse a mongodb document that was converted to JSON in Scala. Make sure that the variable's you're trying to parse are actually in the JSON you're parsing if it is a strict parsing.